# Meaning of "about all..." and "hold on to the hand of..." in the sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

What are the meanings of "about all..." and "hold on to the hand of" in the sentence "There are many times in life when about all we can do is to hold on to the hand of the Divine Guide until we have run through the storm zone." ?

Thanks.

Comment: Parse it as *There are times when* and *nearly all we can do is trust the Divine Guide to lead us*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on incorrect parsing of the sentence.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for comment. I just want to know the meaning of some phrase, What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, I think the writer has omitted the word ***"just"*** as in `"just about there"` which indicates *very little distance left before reaching a destination*, or `"I just about reached it"` which is closer to meaning *very little distance between me and my goal.* or "just about anything we do" which is used to indicate *few optimum choices*. It is used like the word `"almost"` and indicates there is very little of whatever is referred to, such as distance, choices, effort, or whatever follows the phrase.

"hold on to the hand of the Divine Guide" is a complete phrase meaning trust in God, who will lead the way, or hold one steady during an ordeal. To "hold on to the hand" is to submit to the will of God, or to give God one's trust that The Divine Guide (God or Jesus or Allah or even an angel sent from God, depending on one's beliefs) knows what is best when the person in dire straights does not know what to do, or how to get through some difficult situation.

A complete interpretation of the sentence you presented is that sometimes we do not have a solution and we must trust God to get us through to the other side of the problem (storm zone) safely and with the "right" answer or solution. Very religious people use this phrase to say they have no idea how to handle something very difficult, and so they give up volition to a higher power.

*This part is only my *Non-denominational, unbiased* opinion/advice, and does not pertain to the meaning of the sentence, so take it or leave it, as you please. Giving up volition to an unknown power is not always the best solution. Self-determination is highly regarded, even by the very religious. Action is normally better than inaction. Giving up to an unknown could result in something that ends unhappily. In such a case, the very religious tend to say it was God's will, and not their own decision or not the solution they would have chosen. That said, prayer never hurt anyone who also took considered, logical action on their own or their loved one's behalf.

Comment: Thanks for answer and your kind advices.I agree with your opinions but suppose a situation you does not have any idea to solve your problem (for example if my ship is broken in the sea and I can not swim).What do I do? logically, it seems I will die so I "give up" or "trust the God".If I choose the second one I have high self-confidence results from trust of God so I don't give up,I try and think to solve my very difficult problem and in the same time I hope support from infinity power of the creator of great organised world.

Comment: Good point. I concede you are correct. I had not considered such situations, because they fall under the dubious designation of "hopeless" which is a misnomer since hope is still a driving force all the way until one is no longer living.